# Connecting UISegmentedControl with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image]

I want to implement a `UISegmentedControl` to my `UIPageViewController` but i cannot add it, i have to add it on my container view. The issue is that it cannot find the two `ViewController´s` and crashes when i press on the **Segmented control**.

Can i add a **Segmented control** programmatically since i cannot drag and drop it on `UIPageViewController`. I also want to be able to switch views using the **Segmented control**.

**Swift** language

Comment: where do you want the segmentedcontrol to be located?

Comment: i want it to be located on  the container view so it doesn´t move but then the app crashes, and i can´t put it on the pageviewcontroller. I just want it to stay still like the navigationbar @AndréSlotta

Comment: but you want it at the bottom of the view? or where?

Comment: at the top, right under the navigationbar @AndréSlotta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add the segmentedcontrol to the view that contains the containerview. you do not setup any segues from the segmentedcontrol but do it in code:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
  if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RedViewController")
    pageViewController.setViewControllers([vc!], direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
  } else {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BlueViewController")
    pageViewController.setViewControllers([vc!], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

take a look at my demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sa92iwqmb72dyih/AAByJaLJ_Wk24FMwQcWazPcHa?dl=0

Comment: `pageViewController.setViewControllers([vc!]` i can not make this line to work, any explanation on what to put in there?

Comment: i fixed it after i checked out your example code :)

Comment: Also, when i swipe the segmented control does not follow and change indicator. Why is that?

Comment: if you want that you have to implement the pageviewcontrollers datasource instead of just setting the viewcontrollers via `setViewControllers...`

Comment: and how is that possible?

Comment: like this: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sa92iwqmb72dyih/AAByJaLJ_Wk24FMwQcWazPcHa?dl=0

Comment: It still does not work, i did not change anything. Is it because i still got code in my `UIPageViewController` that handles the sliding?

Comment: take a look at my sample and compare it to your code.

Comment: I did, it should work like yours but it does not, i connect all the outlets. I still don´t think my `UIPageViewController` is not connected with the segmented control